# Importing a .csv or .xlsx file to arcgis online/pro as a polygon..?

Tags: csv, arcgis

I queried some data from UNHCR for a refugee resettlement project on Syrian resettlement trends from 2010-2020 in four specific countries (Canada, France, Germany and USA) and have it saved as a .csv file. I am wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to create a feature class associated with the Country name or ISO-3166 alpha 2 code (for example, France or FR) to be a polygon coinciding with a country. I have been able to save this .csv as a point feature class and have looked on the ESRI help forums which give instructions however each time I import the file to ArcGIS Online it only displays as a point feature. If anyone has any insights or workarounds it would be greatly appreciated! I also have access to ArcGIS Pro if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find a polygon feature class with the country boundaries to join the CSV data to (maybe see here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23028/getting-polygons-of-all-countries-and-iso-3166-2-subdivisons). It sounds like the CSV just has one point (probably a centroid of the country) in it.

I also recommend you join https://gis.stackexchange.com as well to ask about the joins etc